# Swift NSPredicate with enum parameters

Tags: swift, enums, nspredicate

I am trying to retrieve SISLItem objects, filtering them through a predicate, which aggregates parameters with “IN”.

## SISLItem class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(SISLItem)

class SISLItem: NSManagedObject {

  @NSManaged var needDate: NSDate?
  @NSManaged var purchaseStatus: NSNumber
  @NSManaged var isProposed: NSNumber
  @NSManaged var slEntry: SISLEntry?

}
```

## SISLItem extension

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension SISLItem {

  //  MARK: - Variables

  enum PurchaseStatus: Int16 {
    case
      Cancelled = -1,
      Open,
      OnHold,
      Purchased,
      Expired
  }
  …
```

Later, I use it in order to create the predicate within the extension.

```
…
var error: NSError?
let filterStatus: [Int16] = [SISLItem.PurchaseStatus.Open.rawValue, SISLItem.PurchaseStatus.OnHold.rawValue]
let predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(SISLItem.Attribute.PurchaseStatus.name) IN %@“, argumentArray: filterStatus)
let result: [SISLItem] = CoreDataHelper.searchObjectsWithPredicate(entityName: SISLItem.entityName(), predicate: predicate, sortKey: "\(SISLItem.Attribute.ShopListEntry.name).\(SISLEntry.Attribute.Name.name)", sortAscending: true, error: &error) as! [SISLItem]
…
```

I get the following error message:

```
/Users/rs186096/Documents/OneDrive/Entwicklung/XCode/Shop It/Shop It/SISLItemExt.swift:66:36: Cannot find an initializer for type ‘NSPredicate' that accepts an argument list of type '(format: String, argumentArray: [Int16])'
```

Replacing the enum values in *filterStatus* by integer values like *0*, *1*, does not cause this error:

```
let filterStatus = [0, 1]
```

## Update

Changing the enum type to *Int*, it works:

```
enum PurchaseStatus: Int {
…
let filterStatus: [Int] = [SISLItem.PurchaseStatus.Open.rawValue, SISLItem.PurchaseStatus.OnHold.rawValue]
```

Is the use of a specific integer type a known limitation for predicates?

Comment: What do you want to do? Show an example of what should be filtered. Also please reduce your code to a minimum without all the unnecessary details (see [Minimal Working Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example))

Comment: Thank you @Kametrixom,
I want to filter SISLItem (NSManageObject) by its attribute purchaseStatus (Integer16). I can do this perfectly fine creating the predicate with integer values (as mentioned e.g. 0 and 1), but not using enum values, even with rawValue.